# Imprimir dados de TableView com QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Como posso pegar os dados de um `TableView` adicionar no layout `html` e imprimir com `QPrinter`?

Código:

```
   QString html;
   html = "<div>Titulo</div>"
          "<div>etc</div>"
          "<div>etc</div>"
          "<div>"+ ui->tableView->+"</div>"; << tableView


   QPrinter printer;

   QPainter painter;
   painter.begin(&printer);
   painter.drawText(100, 100, 500, 500,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, html);
   painter.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa obter o [`model`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model) de onde o `QTableView` busca os dados, iterar pelos itens e extrair seu conteúdo usando o método [`QAbstractItemModel::data`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data):

```
html += "<table>";
QAbstractItemModel* model = ui->tableView->model();
int rowCount = model->rowCount();
int columnCount = model->columnCount();
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    html += "<tr>";
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(row, column);
        QString text = model->data(index).toString();
        html += "<td>" + text + "</td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
```

Da mesma forma, você pode usar o método [`QAbstractItemModel::headerData`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) para obter o texto dos cabeçalhos e incluí-los no início da tabela.